# Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity in comic adapter how to solved this one

Tags: java, android, android-studio, click, onitemclicklistener

hello friends i am new in android project i have a problem regrading click listener please check code below of mine project and help me guys how can i get out from this problem  here is my output logcat of my project.
here is logcat

```
at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1238)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1225)
    at com.kd.book.Adapter.MyComicAdapter$1.onClick(MyComicAdapter.java:60)
    at com.kd.book.Adapter.MyComicAdapter$MyViewHolder.onClick(MyComicAdapter.java:96)
```

**My code :**

```
    myViewHolder.setRecyclerItemClickListener(new IRecyclerItemClickListener(){ 

@Override 
public void onClick(View view, int position) {
    //save the comic selected 

    Common.comicSelected = comicList.get(position);

    context.startActivity(new Intent(context,ChapterActivity.class)); } }); }
```

Comment: myViewHolder.setRecyclerItemClickListener(new IRecyclerItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                //save the comic selected
                Common.comicSelected = comicList.get(position);
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context,ChapterActivity.class));

            }
        });


    }

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should only be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. Also, please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 option:

**Option 1:**

use

```
 implements View.OnClickListener
```

at the end of your activity and set

```
myViewHolder.setRecyclerItemClickListener(this);
```

then you can call **startActivity** from the implemented method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity()
}
```

**Option 2:**

use a final variable:

```
 final Activity activity = this;
```

and then call the variable in your clickListener

```
activity.startActivity()
```